# Possible to overwrite existing file using Storage Access FrameWork with Google Drive?

Tags: android, android-intent, google-drive-api, storage-access-framework

I am using the Storage Access Framework in Android with the ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT intent to create a text file on Google Drive. Works fine.

But if I store a file called for instance "new.txt" and then 5 minutes later another file also called "new.txt" (with different contents) then there are now two files with the same name (in the same Drive directory).

Is it somehow possible to detect if there is an existing file with that name (and same mimetype) and then overwrite it with the new content with the ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT intent?

I do not want the user to pick the file with an ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT intent, because if there is in fact no previous file (i.e. first time upload), then the user cannot pick the file to be modifed.

I only need to store in Google Drive, not locally on the SD-card.
I know I could use the Google Drive API, but I would prefer if there was a simple solution to this with the Storage Access Framework?

Comment: I might be wrong, but as far as my experience goes, the `Storage Access Framework` is meant for those very simple use cases and if you need to do deeper integration on the Google Drive, you **must** use the `Drive API`

Comment: Yes, I think after looking a lot at it, that it is not possible to do with the storage access framework

Comment: Currently this seems to be impossible (see this bug report: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=234770)